# Unity 2d game platformer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity to create a 2D platformer game but I got some problems.
The problem is I have 2 waypoints which I would like to use in script too, because I would like to Flip the enemy sprite when reach the waypoint.

I tried:

```
if (transform.position.x <= -2)
{
    Vector3 oposcale = transform.localScale;
    oposcale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = oposcale;
}
```

But I guess my enemy sprite never reach that point.

Answer (score 0):

If you only intend to flip, it is better to use the **`SpriteRenderer`** component itself instead of `localScale`. The following codes show how to access the component and flip it.

```cs
private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
private void Start()
{
    spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}

void FlipSprite() => spriteRenderer.flipX = !spriteRenderer.flipX;
```

Also, to complete your work, just run the above method.

```cs
if (transform.position.x <= -2) FlipSprite();
```